# How convert a PrivateKey to SecretKey?

Tags: java, constructor, type-conversion

I need to generate a secret key with the value of a private key and can be stored in a keystore. I need to use the method `setEntry`

Annex of the code:

```
privateKey = keypair.getPrivate();
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protParam = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password);

javax.crypto.SecretKey mySecretKey= null;
KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry skEntry= new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(mySecretKey); 

ks.setEntry("secretKeyAlias", skEntry, protParam);
```

Comment: Why? Why not store the keypair? What's the point of a private key without the public key?

Comment: And what makes you think you can use an (enormous) private key as a `SecretKey`?

Answer (score 5):

Believe this is not possible.

Logically a [SecretKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html) represents a symmetric key where as a [PrivateKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PrivateKey.html) is part of a PublicKey and Private-Key Pair.

Additionally, in terms of object modelling they are both interfaces. Hence one cannot be 'converted' into another (unless a class exists which implements both interfaces but that does not make sense).

Comment: then as store the private key in a keystore not yet have the certificate, because if it is null generates an exception

Comment: @user3308503 Incomprehensible. Please restate that in standard English.